What are the number of unpaired electrons in Fe+1 ion
I am confused some place the answer is 3 and some show 5

Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.


Iron has 4 unpaired 3d electrons. To form a Fe 1+ ion, remove 1 electron from 4s (highest energy) and so you get 5 unpaired electrons (4 in the 3d and 1 in the 4s)
